# Unwanted Triggering in MOSFET driver circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, mosfet-driver

I am trying to drive a resistive load with an N-channel MOSFET in linear region. This is the circuit I first [simulated](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000049999999999999996+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0At+928+256+896+256+0+1+-2.767299668580683+1.0277902136307231e-9+100%0Ar+784+208+704+208+0+15000%0Ag+704+352+704+368+0%0Aw+576+144+656+144+0%0Aw+576+352+656+352+0%0Ar+576+144+576+240+0+1000%0Av+576+352+576+240+0+0+40+24+0+0+0.5%0Aw+656+352+704+352+0%0Aw+656+240+656+352+0%0Aw+656+176+656+192+0%0Ar+704+208+704+352+0+100000%0Aw+656+224+656+240+0%0Aw+656+144+656+176+0%0Af+704+208+656+208+0+1.3+0.02%0AR+896+144+896+112+0+0+40+24+0+0+0.5%0Aw+880+224+896+224+0%0Ar+928+256+976+256+0+1000%0At+816+224+784+224+0+1+0.6142330554881184+0.6440296367720886+100%0Ar+816+224+880+224+0+1000%0Ar+896+144+896+224+0+10000%0Aw+896+272+896+352+0%0Aw+784+240+784+352+0%0Ar+784+208+784+144+0+10000%0AR+784+144+784+96+0+0+40+24+0+0+0.5%0Aw+784+352+896+352+0%0Aw+704+352+784+352+0%0Aw+896+224+896+240+0%0Ar+928+256+928+352+0+10000%0Aw+896+352+928+352+0%0As+976+256+1040+256+0+1+false%0AR+1040+256+1040+208+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0A) and then built on a prototype board. The signal is triggered by a 5V MCU signal, but for convenience I just replaced it with a pushbutton.

The problem I am facing is the unwanted triggering of mosfet. For example, I would get a DMM to check voltage across V1 and when I remove it the mosfet would get triggered. And it would not turn off for a while or until after I put the probes back across V1.

This description is strange but I'd appreciate if you could help me understand this random triggering. Is there something I am missing?
Is there a different approach possible for triggering the MOSFET in its linear region in this case?

Thank you!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffhTRZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are V1 and V2 physically separate sources in your test circuit? And what device is the physical V3 in your test circuit? Is your circuit stable?. Does it catch something from a phone? I cannot see any decoupling nor bandwidth limiting capacitors. If this is built with long wires on a breadboard there are very good chances for unpredictable behaviour. You can easily dampen talks like this by providing a photo of well constructed test circuit.

Comment: @user287001 Yes, V1 and V2 are separate sources. V3 is a 5V PIC controller 16f18324, just to provide a signal. I did not check the stability of circuit because I actually don't know how to. I am not sure how and where to use the decoupling capacitors, but it seems that they may help with the interference. I built it on a general prototype PCB. I wont get the photo until after the weekend now haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- make sure all gnds are common =0V
- R3 is almost redundant but necessary because you have 24V instead of 12~18V Vgs ideal with >3x Vgs(th)max yet < absolute max Vgs of 20V.

Probe gnd is probably fixing a gnd wiring error.

Since RdsOn is = 4 mohm (low) , Qgs is big 32mC which also affects speed of gate with R2=15k

With Trevor’s suggestion of R4=100 ohms Vgs max is now 24V(100k/(100k+R4) which MUST NOT exceed 20V. Thus he suggested R4=100k.  It can be any ratio that results in 12V to 18V with 2V safety margin on high side and low side to ensure low RdsOn.

Normally in high speed PWM designs Gate driver resistance is been 2000 and 200 x RdsOn or as per data sheet 2000x4 mohm =8 ohms so one might use a Vcc of 12V for Vgs drivers using 4V threshold type FETs

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like the gate of the M1 is actually floating.  Check its connections.  With the gate floating, any capacitive pickup from nearby things, like your hands or scope probes, can cause unpredictable effects.

Another issue is that the gate voltage is very high when M1 is supposed to be on.  With Q1 off, you have a 25 kΩ and 100 kΩ divider from 24 V.  That comes out to 19.2 V, which is above the maximum allowed gate voltage of some FETs.  Check the datasheet.  Most FETs are fully on with 12 V gate drive, even if they can handle up to 20 V on the gate.  I don't see any drawback in changing your divider to result in a lower value.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening! But I thought the pull down resistor R3 will ensure that gate float does not float. Connections still look fine though. Thank you so much for the heads up about gate voltage! I will make sure my gate voltage is sufficient enough to stay in linear region.

Comment: Should there also be pull-down resistor at the base of Q1?

Comment: @Amy: No.  There is a passive pull up, and a active pull down.

Comment: @AmyM Make R2 100 ohms and R4 100K